# Django migrations reference a deleted module

Tags: django, migration, django-migrations

I have a `Model` named `FooModel` defined in a `my_app/models/foo.py`.

After deleting `foo.py`, running Django (1.7) migrations raises an error since the old migration files import `foo.py` (`import myapp.models.foo.FooModel`).

How should I resolve this?

This happens when the model has an `ImageField` with an `upload_to` parameter.

Comment: Have you deleted `FooModel` or moved it?

Comment: Sometimes, I delete, this time I moved it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two cases:

1. You moved `FooModel` elsewhere, then edit all your migration files to reflect that move.
2. You removed `FooModel`, in this case, follow these steps:

   - Put `FooModel` back to where it was.
   - Make sure there are no references to `FooModel` elsewhere in your code.
   - Run `./manage.py makemigrations my_app`
   - Run `./manage.py squashmigrations my_app <migration created with the previous comand>` — see the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#more-advanced-migrations) for more informations on squashing migrations.
   - Repeat the two previous steps for any app that references `FooModel` in its migrations.
   - Remove `FooModel` and the stale migration files once you ensured everything worked fine.

This should work because as `FooModel` is not referenced from any other model, it should be removed from the migrations files when squashing them.

However, be warned that squashing migrations is not a simple operation and may have consequences it might be a better idea to just keep the model in your codebase without using it.

Note: in this situation, the object in question is a Django model but this applies to any class, function or module referenced by migration files.

Comment: Thanks! hoped there would be an easy solution. But good to know the best option available at the moment as well.

Comment: Oh wow, thank you! I didn't know you can squash migrations. In my case it was even simpler, just squashing the app which migrations referenced the deleted model did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

In custom database migrations you should not import your models directly because you can face this particular issue in the future. Instead you should rather use Djangos `get_model` function.

```
MyModel = apps.get_model('myapp', 'MyModel')
for row in MyModel.objects.all():
    row.uuid = uuid.uuid4()
    row.save(update_fields=['uuid'])
```

In this case the migrations will also run when you decide to delete the model in the future.

Further read: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/writing-migrations/

Comment: What about regular classes (not models)? In that case, we can't use `apps.get_model()`. How do you deal with deleted classes imported in migrations in this case?